# Make Django 1.8 raise error for missing templates

Tags: python, django, templates, testing

My test suite was passing just fine, but when I fired up `runserver` I found out I was missing a template specified in an `{% include %}` tag. The point of tests is to alert me to problems like this, but Django sets `DEBUG=False` during tests, silencing `TemplateDoesNotExist` errors.

If there any way to get the desired behavior without completely redefining my `TEMPLATES` setting during tests?